# Linux Mint Change Screen Resolution

Tags: linux-mint, display-settings

I installed Linux mint 10.I have nvidia geforce 9500 GT.After installing `nvidia-current` package,my screen resolution become 800*600.There is no 1024*768 in Monitors menu.

Running `inxi -Gx` shows,

```
Graphics:  Card nVidia G96 [GeForce 9500 GT] X.Org 1.9.0 Res: 800x600@61.0hz 
           GLX Renderer N/A GLX Version N/A Direct Rendering N/A
```

No idea what is going wrong.Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the problem.`xorg.conf` file was missing.Ran this command `sudo Xorg -configure` and created it.Finally restart the computer