# Surface Go-3 how to set a non standard screen resolution for stylus

Tags: xrandr, resolution, touch-screen, surface

Mint+MATE-20.3: The Surface GO-3 has a native aspect ratio of 3:2 (1920 x 1280). Tired old eyes and I need to use a resolution around 1440 wide and the only options are 1440x900, 1440x810 and 1400x900. All are fine for the eyes, but the stylus defaults to what I think is the 3:2 screen ratio and none of those are that.

Left/right the pointer matches the stylus tip. Up/down is only correct in the vertical center of the screen. At the top the pointer is below the stylus and at the bottom, above it. The error increase proportionally with direction.

[I found this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120291/how-to-get-external-monitor-resolution-set-by-xrandr-to-persist?newreg=8daab93843e44bbd8f70af6fe93ea7f0) and "xrandr" shows "eDP-1 current 1440 x 900" and a long list of others.

I have tried all of the options in that link and I cannot get my 1440 x 960 (3:2) resolution added or used. None of those commands caused any errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ ! -t 0 ]
  then
    cvt 1440 960
    xrandr --newmode "1440x960_60.00"  113.75  1440 1528 1672 1904  960 963 973 996 -hsync +vsync
    xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1440x960_60.00"
fi
```

How can I get the stylus and the pointer to hold hands?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Surface Go 3 with Arch Linux and I'm running the *Sway* window manager (SwayWM - on Wayland, not Xorg). I also wanted a lower resolution, and also wanted to avoid scaling, which is supported by SwayWM. By default, the only listed resolution for the Surface display is 1920x1280 (from 'swaymsg -t get_outputs').

In any case, I was able to set the following in Sway's config file:

```
output eDP-1 mode --custom 1440x960@60hZ
```

.. and it works as intended.

I'm not sure how much this can help, it may suggest as a possible solution either to move to a desktop environment / window manager that supports Wayland (perhaps based on *wlroots*), or - instead - to a distribution that has a newer kernel / Intel driver?