# Linux Mint 21.1 Cinnamon Screen resolution issue

Tags: cinnamon, intel-graphics, resolution

The issue is that the desktop's resolution was working well, then after a reboot it set to the default low res. If I set it to 1600x900, then the display ends about 1.5 cm from the top of the screen and is about 5 pixels too left. Another complication is that I have a VGA switch between the PC and the monitor. I ran "Custom Screen Resolution GUI" and it calculated the screen res max to be 1920x1080. I can create and add the new mode (as it isn't in xrandr's list) but I can't switch to it.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 256mm x 192mm
   1024x768      60.00 +
   1600x900      60.00* 
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1366x768      59.79  
   1280x720      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   1920x1080_60.00  59.98  
   3840x2160_60.00  59.98  
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync --verbose
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
```

I've scanned the similar questions. The graphics card is an onboard one, so no nvidia driver issues. I have tried [Change screen resolution on Linux Mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67700/change-screen-resolution-on-linux-mint) but keeps getting to the same fault. I also used ChatGPT to assist in the commands to diagnose the issue.  These are the suggested commands and results after I told it about the BadName error:

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i error
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
```

```
$ xrdb -query
*customization: -color
Xft.dpi:    96
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
Xft.rgba:   rgb
```

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
```

Then it ran out of suggestions. (Our IT jobs are still safe ;-))

**Any suggestion what next command to run to diagnose the issue?**

Comment: VGA is a very old and universal format. It is not supposed to be used at high resolution. Nowadays, VGA is a rescue mode, if native drivers fail.  What are your native drivers? What is your video card?

Comment: @WhiteOwl the OP has included `lspci` output showing the card details.

Comment: Had to do a hard shut down and boot up, now 1920x1080 (without the _60.00) is in the list of the Display app and I could set it to that value and it works. Not sure why it didn't work the whole day with multiple reboots...